# Quadratic ellipsoid form to translation vector and angle ($\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$)

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

I would like to solve an arbitrary ellipsoid from a set of 3D data points. To
achieve this I thought of solving a set of quadratic equations and then
compute the associated parameters.

Lacking mathematical background, I read many articles to complete my goal.

I found that the general form of an ellipsoid centered at origin is (as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid)):

(1) $\frac{x}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} = 1$

I found that the general quadratic equation of an ellipsoid is (as per [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html)):

(2) $Ax^{2} + By^{2} + Cz^{2} + 2Fyz + 2Gzx + 2Hxy + 2Px + 2Qy + 2Rz = 0$

The ellipsoid I would like to solve can be translated and rotated. I found that
the transformation matrix to accomplish these transformations are (as per this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)):

$Rz(\alpha) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\
    \sin(\alpha) &  \cos(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\
               0 &             0 & 1 & 0 \\
               0 &             0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$Ry(\beta) = \begin{bmatrix}
     \cos(\beta) & 0 & \sin(\beta) & 0 \\
               0 & 1 &           0 & 0 \\
    -\sin(\beta) & 0 & \cos(\beta) & 0 \\
               0 & 0 &           0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$Rx(\gamma) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 &            0 &             0 & 0 \\
    0 & \cos(\gamma) & -\sin(\gamma) & 0 \\
    0 & \sin(\gamma) &  \cos(\gamma) & 0 \\
    0 &            0 &             0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$T = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & x_{0} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & y_{0} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & z_{0} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$P = T.Rz(\alpha).Ry(\beta).Rx(\gamma)$
$P = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha) & \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) & \sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) & x_{0} \\
    \cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) & y_{0} \\
               -\sin(\beta) &                                        \sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta) &                                        \cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta) & z_{0} \\
                          0 &                                                              0 &                                                              0 &     1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

From there, I am able to transform a point ($x$, $y$, $z$) to a translated and
rotated version ($x'$, $y'$, $z'$) of itself:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    x' \\
    y' \\
    z' \\
    1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
P
\begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
    x' \\
    y' \\
    z' \\
    1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha) + y(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)) + z(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)) + x_{0} \\
    x\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha) + y(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)) + z(\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)-\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)) + y_{0} \\
                                                                                             -x\sin(\beta) + y\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta) + z\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta) + z_{0} \\
                                                                                                                                                                       1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Injecting this new point into $(1)$ gives the equation for any arbitrary ellipsoid.

Now I want to develop the equation $(1)$ and then factorize an other way in order to find the expression of the terms in $(2)$: $A$, $B$, $C$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $P$, $Q$, $R$.

After this, I could get the following expression for the terms of $(2)$. Note that if you are interested in the details, they are posted at the very end of the question.

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A &= x^{2}\left[ \frac{\cos^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
B &= y^{2}\left[ \frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\alpha) - 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
C &= z^{2}\left[ \frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\alpha) - 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{cos^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
2F &= 2yz\left[ \frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) - \sin^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) - \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) - \cos^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) + \sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) - \sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
2G &= 2zx\left[ \frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{a^{2}} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta) - \cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{-\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
2H &= 2xy\left[ \frac{\cos^{2}(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta) - \cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{b^{2}} + \frac{-\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
2P &= 2x\left[ \frac{x_{0}\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{y_{0}\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{-z_{0}\sin(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
2Q &= 2y\left[ \frac{x_{0}\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - x_{0}\cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{y_{0}\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + y_{0}\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{z_{0}\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right] \\
2R &= 2z\left[ \frac{x_{0}\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + x_{0}\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}} + \frac{y_{0}\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - y_{0}\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)}{b^{2}} + \frac{z_{0}\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}} \right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Note: although I spent a lot of time developing the equation $(1)$, I am not 100%  confident that no mistake got in at some point ..

**Q:** How can I find the following functions $f_{i}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R)$ ?

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\alpha &= f_{1}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R) \\
\beta  &= f_{2}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R) \\
\gamma &= f_{3}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R) \\
x_{0}  &= f_{4}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R) \\
y_{0}  &= f_{5}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R) \\
z_{0}  &= f_{6}(A, B, C, F, G, H, P, Q, R) \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

**DETAILS:** Bellow are the details of the previous developments to find $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $P$, $Q$, and $R$.

I used the following remarkable identity $(a + b + c + d)^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2} + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc + 2ad + 2bd + 2cd$ to develop the squared terms in $(1)$ after replace $x$, $y$, $z$ by $x'$, $y'$, $z'$.

**1) develop of part 1 of (1) $\frac{x'^{2}}{a^{2}}$**

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a &= x\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha) \\
b &= y(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)) \\
c &= z(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)) \\
d &= x_{0} \\
\\
a^{2} &= x^{2}\frac{\cos^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
b^{2} &= y^{2}\frac{(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha))^{2}}{a^{2}} \\
      &= y^{2}\frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\alpha) - 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
c^{2} &= z^{2}\frac{(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha))^{2}}{a^{2}} \\
      &= z^{2}\frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + 2\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
      &= z^{2}\frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
d^{2} &= \frac{x_{0}^{2}}{a^{2}} \\
\\
2ab &= 2xy\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha))}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2xy\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2xy\frac{\cos^{2}(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta) - \cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
\\
2ac &= 2xz\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha))}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2xz\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2xz\frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + \cos^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{a^{2}} \\
\\
2bc &= 2yz\frac{(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha))(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha))}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2yz\frac{\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2yz\frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\beta)\cos^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) - \sin^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) - \cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
\\
2ad &= 2x\frac{x_{0}\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
\\
2bd &= 2y\frac{x_{0}(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha))}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2y\frac{x_{0}\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - x_{0}\cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)}{a^{2}} \\
\\
2cd &= 2z\frac{x_{0}(\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha))}{a^{2}} \\
    &= 2z\frac{x_{0}\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + x_{0}\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{a^{2}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

**2) develop of part 2 of (1) $\frac{y'^{2}}{b^{2}}$**

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a &= x\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha) \\
b &= y(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)) \\
c &= z(\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)) \\
d &= y_{0} \\
\\
a^{2} &= x^{2}\frac{\cos^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
b^{2} &= y^{2}\frac{(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))^{2}}{b^{2}} \\
      &= y^{2}\frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + 2\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
      &= y^{2}\frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
c^{2} &= z^{2}\frac{(\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha))^{2}}{b^{2}} \\
      &= z^{2}\frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\alpha) - 2\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
      &= z^{2}\frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\alpha) - 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
d^{2} &= \frac{y_{0}^{2}}{b^{2}} \\
\\
2ab &= 2xy\frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2xy\frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2xy\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) + \sin^{2}(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{b^{2}} \\
2ac &= 2xz\frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)(\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha))}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2xz\frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2xz\frac{\sin^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta) - \cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
2bc &= 2yz\frac{(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))(\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha))}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2yz\frac{\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2yz\frac{\cos^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha) - \cos^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) + \sin^{2}(\beta)\sin^{2}(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma) - \sin^{2}(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
2ad &= 2x\frac{y_{0}\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
2bd &= 2y\frac{y_{0}(\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha))}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2y\frac{y_{0}\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + y_{0}\sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha)}{b^{2}} \\
2cd &= 2z\frac{y_{0}(\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha))}{b^{2}} \\
    &= 2z\frac{y_{0}\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - y_{0}\sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)}{b^{2}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

**3) develop of part 3 of (1) $\frac{z'^{2}}{c^{2}}$**

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a &= -x\sin(\beta) \\
b &= y\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta) \\
c &= z\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta) \\
d &= z_{0} \\
\\
a^{2} &= x^{2}\frac{\sin^{2}(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
b^{2} &= y^{2}\frac{\sin^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
c^{2} &= z^{2}\frac{cos^{2}(\gamma)\cos^{2}(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
d^{2} &= \frac{z_{0}^{2}}{c^{2}} \\
\\
2ab &= 2xy\frac{-\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
    &= 2xy\frac{-\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
2ac &= 2xz\frac{-\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
    &= 2xz\frac{-\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
2bc &= 2yz\frac{\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
    &= 2yz\frac{\cos^{2}(\beta)\cos(\gamma)\sin(\gamma)}{c^{2}} \\
2ad &= 2x\frac{-z_{0}\sin(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
2bd &= 2y\frac{z_{0}\sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}} \\
2cd &= 2z\frac{z_{0}\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{c^{2}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set of data points $\{ P_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i) , i = 1, N\}, N \ge 9 $, you want to fit these points to the model

$ A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + D xy + E xz + F yz + G x + H y + I z + J = 0 $

For that, you construct an error function $\mathbf{E}$ defined as follows

$ \mathbf{E} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N (A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + D xy + E xz + F yz + G x + H y + I z + J)^2 $

And you minimize this function.  To ensure that you get a valid ellipsoid with the parameters $A$ through $J$ not all zero, you make the minimization conditioned on the constraint $A + B + C = 1 $

Substitute for $A$ in the above expression you get

$ \mathbf{E} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)^2 $

Differentiating $\mathbf{E}$ with respect to $B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I$ and $J$ results in the following equations for the minimum

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N  ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J) (y_i^2 - x_i^2) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)  (x_i y_i) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)  (x_i z_i) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)  (y_i z_i) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)  (x_i) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J)  (y_i) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J) (z_i) = 0 $

$ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N ( ( x_i^2 + B (y_i^2 - x_i^2) + C (z_i^2 - x_i^2) + D x_i y_i + E x_i z_i + F y_i z_i + G x_i + H y_i + I z_i + J) = 0 $

The above 9 equations lead to the following linear system for finding $B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J$

Define the vector $X = [B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]^T $, then the normal equations are

$ \mathbf{A} X = Y $

where

$ \mathbf{A} = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N A_i $

with

$A_i =  \begin{bmatrix} (y_i^2 - x_i^2)^2 &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2)(y_i^2 - x_i^2) &&  x_i y_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) && x_i z_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) &&  y_i z_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) && x_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) &&  y_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) && z_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) && (y_i^2 - x_i^2 ) \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (z_i^2 - x_i^2) && (z_i^2 - x_i^2)^2 &&  x_i y_i (z_i^2 - x_i^2) && x_i z_i (z_i^2 - x_i^2) &&  y_i z_i (z_i^2 - x_i^2) && x_i (z_i^2 - x_i^2) &&  y_i (z_i^2 - x_i^2) && z_i (z_i^2 - x_i^2) && (z_i^2 - x_i^2 )\\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (x_i y_i) &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) (x_i y_i) &&  (x_i y_i)^2 && x_i^2 y_i z_i &&  x_i y_i^2 z_i && x_i^2 y_i  &&  x_i y_i^2  && x_i y_i z_i  && x_i y_i \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (x_i z_i) &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) (x_i z_i) &&  x_i^2 y_i z_i && x_i^2 z_i^2 &&  x_i y_i z_i^2 && x_i (x_i z_i)  &&   y_i (x_i z_i)  && z_i (x_i z_i)  && x_i z_i \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (y_i z_i) &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) (y_i z_i) &&  (x_i y_i)(y_i z_i) && (x_i z_i) (y_i z_i) && (y_i z_i)^2   && x_i (y_i z_i)  &&   y_i (y_i z_i)  && z_i (y_i z_i)  && y_i z_i \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (x_i) &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) (x_i) &&  (x_i y_i)(x_i) && (x_i z_i) (x_i) && (y_i z_i)(x_i)   && x_i^2  &&   y_i (x_i)  && z_i (x_i)  && x_i \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (y_i) &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) (y_i) &&  (x_i y_i)(y_i) && (x_i z_i) (y_i) && (y_i z_i)(y_i)   && x_i y_i  &&   y_i^2  && z_i (y_i)  && y_i \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2) (z_i) &&  (z_i^2 - x_i^2) (z_i) &&  (x_i y_i)(z_i) && (x_i z_i) (z_i) && (y_i z_i)(z_i)   && x_i z_i  &&   y_i z_i  && z_i ^2  && z_i \\
(y_i^2 - x_i^2)  && (z_i^2 - x_i^2) &&  (x_i y_i) && (x_i z_i) && (y_i z_i)   && x_i   &&   y_i  && z_i  && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

And

$ Y = \begin{bmatrix} - \sum x_i^2 (y_i^2 - x_i^2) \\
- \sum x_i^2 (z_i - x_i)^2 \\
- \sum x_i^2 (x_i y_i) \\
- \sum x_i^2 (x_i z_i) \\
- \sum x_i^2 (y_i z_i) \\
- \sum x_i^2 (x_i) \\
- \sum x_i^2 (y_i) \\
- \sum x_i^2 (z_i) \\
- \sum x_i^2 \end{bmatrix}$

Now we have our linear system which can be solve for the parameter vector $X$ using Gauss-Jordan elimination, which is a standard routine.  Having found $X$ all the parameters of the ellipsoid are known, and it can be written in quadratic form as

$ r^T Q r = 0 $

where $r = [x, y, z, 1]^T$ , and

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} A && D/2 && E/2 && G/2 \\ D/2 && B && F/2 && H/2 \\ E/2 && F/2 && C && I/2 \\ G/2 && H/2 && I/2 && J \end{bmatrix} $

Now define the $3 \times 3$ matrix

$ Q_0 = \begin{bmatrix} A && D / 2 && E / 2 \\ D / 2 && B && F/2 \\ E/2 && F/2 && C \end{bmatrix}$

and the vector

$ b = [G , H, I ]^T $

Then the center of this ellipsoid is given by

$ P = - \dfrac{1}{2} Q_0^{-1} b $

Which enables us to write the equation of the fitted ellipsoid in the form

$ (p - P)^T Q_0 (p - P) = P^T Q_0 P - J $

where $p = [x, y, z]^T $

Dividing both sides by $(P^T Q_0 P - J) $ gives us

$ (p - P)^T Q_1 (p - P) = 1$

where $Q_1 = Q_0 / (P^T Q_0 P - J) $

This is the standard equation of an ellipsoid.  If you want to find the semi-axes and their directions, then you have to diagonalize $Q_1$ into

$Q_1 = R D R^T $

The diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix $D$ are just the reciprocals of the squared semi-axes lengths.  In other words

$ D = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{a^2} && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{1}{b^2} && 
0 \\ 0 && 0 && \dfrac{1}{c^2} \end{bmatrix} $

while each of the columns of the orthogonal matrix $R$ points in the direction of the corresponding semi-axis.

**Appendix:**

To relate the found $R$ to the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ which specify the rotations about the principal axes $z$, then $y$ , then $x$, and this leads to

$ R = R_z(\alpha) R_y(\beta) R_x(\gamma) $

The expansion of the right-hand side is given in the original post, and  is given by

$ R = R_z(\alpha) R_y(\beta) R_x(\gamma) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha) & \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) & \sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)  \\
    \cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)  \\
               -\sin(\beta) &                                        \sin(\gamma)\cos(\beta) &                                        \cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)  \end{bmatrix}$

Consider the first column of the matrix on the right-hand side, it tells us that

$ R_{31} = -\sin(\beta) $

From which we can solve for $\beta = \sin^{-1}\bigg( - R_{31} \bigg) $

Next, we have,

$ R_{11} = \cos(\beta) \cos(\alpha) $

$R_{21} = \cos(\beta) \sin(\alpha)$

Therefore, $ \alpha = \text{atan2} \bigg( R_{11}, R_{21} \bigg) $

Also, we have

$ R_{32} = \sin(\gamma) \cos(\beta) $

$ R_{33} = \cos(\gamma) \cos(\beta) $

Therefore, $\gamma = \text{atan2} \bigg( R_{33}, R_{32} \bigg) $

Comment: Thank you very much for these well detailed explanations. Although I read your answer many times with external resources (thus the late acknowledgment), I could compute the ellipsoid parameters \o/

Comment: For testing purpose, I made a small program which generates a known transformation matrix $P$ from a set of random ($x_{0}$, $y_{0}$, $z_{0}$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$). Transforms a unit sphere into an ellipsoid and feed a few points to your algorithm. In the end it plots the resulting parameters to visually verify the results.

I cannot (yet) resolve angles from base $R$. I am trying to extract this using cross product between axis but I am not there yet! If you have hints on this part it would perfects your (already excellent) answer.

Comment: I'll append my answer with how to find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, but I am engaged at the moment with an urgent issue.  So, check in about 2 hours.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Comment: I was close on my first try as $R$ can be assimilated to the rotation matrix $Rz(\alpha).Ry(\beta).Rx(\gamma)$ defined in the question. However I was using $\gamma = \sin^{-1}(\frac{r_{32}}{\cos(\beta)})$ and $\alpha = \cos^{-1}(\frac{r_{11}}{\cos(beta)})$ which produced inconsistent results from one set to an other ..

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: Actually there may be something wrong with the angles .. When creating a transformation matrix from the computed ellipsoid parameters and then transforming a unit sphere we do not get aligned with the original ellipsoid..

Comment: Q: Plotting columns of $R$ as vectors show that the angle between each vectors of the base is not $\pi/2$. Why aren't they orthogonal?

Comment: The columns of $R$ which is produced by diagonalizing $Q_1$ are always orthogonal.  Check your diagonalization software routine.

Comment: They are indeed, it was a perspective visual effect. Do you have any idea why the base $R$ is not equal to the reference base (origin) transformed by $Rz(\alpha).Ry(\beta).Rx(\gamma)$? I mean, axis are not aligned ; there is(are) extra rotation(s) applied which varies between tests but is(are) mostly around $+/-\pi$ and $+/-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: The columns of matrix $R$ represent the semi-axes direction, but this can work in either direction, in other words, the columns of $R$ are correct up to a sign, and you can replace any column of $R$ with its negative.  This explains the extra rotation of $180^\circ$.  I don't think there could an extra rotation of $\pm 90^\circ$.